# AWS: Sync WWW folder between multiple load balanced instances

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I am new to AWS. I am trying to setup an EC2 web server. I got the server up and running, I made the AMI (which included the WWW folder), added the load balancer etc. I terminated the original instance.

I would now like to upload some files to the WWW folder, so that I can modify my website. However, I can not figure out how.

I assume that I was supposed to do something such as share the www folder between the instances.

Here are the problems that I am thinking of:

1. How to I use SFTP (winSCP) to connect to the WWW folder?
2. If I change the WWW folder on one instance, does the change propagate to the others?
3. If not, how do I create a shared WWW folder?
4. How do I modify apache to point to the shared WWW folder?

My setup:

- AWS VPC in N. Virginia
- AMI with current website data in /var/www/http folder
- Website is drupal based
- RDS storing drupal database
- phpmyadmin also in www folder, using to control RDS

Comment: Have you looked at the AWS application management services such as Elastic Beanstalk and OpsWorks? It's more common to automatically deploy code files to multiple instances than to actually share the same set of files.